# Jenkins maven job fails with " Failed to execute goal on project XX:"

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I have installed maven external jars in my local .m2 repository. My project builds successfully when I build it using command line. But when I build it using Jenkins I get the error " Failed to execute goal on project XX:Could not resolve dependencies for project XXX:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: " 
My .m2 repo contains all required jars. 
Plesae help me with this problem 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins have its own .m2 repository located by default in JENKINS_HOME. You should also install your artifacts in this repository.
Hope that will help you to solve your issue.